# Строка поиска поверх элементов меню

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально `input` поиска не видно, он появляется при наведении на лупу и двигает всё меню, как можно сделать чтобы `input` становился поверх остальных пунктов меню?

```
<section class="header">
    <div class="header-inner">
        <img src="img/menu.svg">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Bondi" class="logo">
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="nav-list">
                <li class="nav-list__item active">Home</li>
                <li class="nav-list__item">Services</li>
                <li class="nav-list__item">Portfolio</li>
                <li class="nav-list__item">About</li>
                <li class="nav-list__item">Contact</li>
            </div>
            <div class="search">
                <input class="search__input" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                <img  src="img/search.svg" class="search__icon" alt="">
            </div>
            <button class="btn">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


.search {
    padding: 0 15px;
    border-left: 1px solid #00C6BF;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.search:hover > .search__input {
    width: 200px;
}

.search__icon {
    width: 24px;
}

.search__input {
    border: none;
    font-style: 18px;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
    width: 0;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
}

.search__input:focus {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: position:absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при `hover` скрываем `span` внутри которого иконка

`input` растягиваем на 100% `form` а при `hover` изменяем ширину на 50%

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav,
ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

ul {
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

form {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: width .5s linear;
}

form:hover {
  width: 50%;
}

form:hover span {
  display: none;
}

form input[type="search"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

form:hover input[type="search"] {
  visibility: visible;
}

form span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: none;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p class="logo">logo</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form action="">
    <input type="search">
    <span>&#128269;</span>
  </form>

</nav>
```

Comment: а можно вот из вашего примера чтобы инпут не отталкивал пункты меню,а поверх них становился? тем самым перекрывая их

Comment: Добавил свой пример

Comment: @Алексей  так примерно : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/JvERYR?editors=0100